# How are system services restarted?

Tags: android

I'm trying to restart the mediadrmserver on the Android Emulator by modifying "/etc/init/mediadrmserver.rc" and then restarting the mediadrm service. However, I notice mediadrm restarts just fine even when there is an error in mediadrmserver.rc.

This brings me to my question: How are services started on Android? How do I launch a service with a custom command?

What I would finally like to achieve is to run valgrind on mediadrmserver using the steps given in [Using Valgrind](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/valgrind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mediadrm service does indeed start the mediadrmserver process using "/etc/init/mediadrmserver.rc". The problem I was running into was that the mediadrm service wasn't recognizing the changes I had made to the ".rc" file during relaunch. Modifying the ".rc" file and then restarting the emulator fixed the problem for me.

As for what I was trying to achieve, I ran mediadrmserver through valgrind, using the steps given [here](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/valgrind) (also applies to any service/process), and I compiled valgrind for the Android emulator, using the steps given in Valgrind's [README.android](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.readme-android.html).

However, I couldn't get it to work (valgrind crashes with SIGSEV) because it looks like valgrind only works on emulators running Android versions up to ICS (4.0.3). Furthermore, Google plans to remove Valgrind from the platform in a future release and recommends using [Address Sanitizer](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/asan) instead.